# Making LINQ to a dictionary into a method body

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I am using two almost identical (the only exception is that one got `.ToDictinct()`, and the other one doesn't) calls. Is it possible to make them into a one method that I can call and change in one place?

```
private void Splitter1(string[] file)
{               
    tempDict = file
        .SelectMany(i => File.ReadAllLines(i)
        .SelectMany(line => line.Split(new[] { ' ', ',', '.', '?', '!', '{', '[', '(', '}', ']', ')',
        '<', '>', '-', '=', '/', '"', ';', ':', '+', '_', '*' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))                    
        .AsParallel()
        .Select(word => word.ToLower()) 
        .Where(word => !StopWords.Contains(word))
        .Where(word => !PopulatNetworkWords.Contains(word)) 
        .Where(word => !word.All(char.IsDigit))
        .Distinct())
        .GroupBy(word => word)                    
        .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
}
private void Splitter2(string[] file)
{               
    tempDict = file
        .SelectMany(i => File.ReadAllLines(i)
        .SelectMany(line => line.Split(new[] { ' ', ',', '.', '?', '!', '{', '[', '(', '}', ']', ')',
        '<', '>', '-', '=', '/', '"', ';', ':', '+', '_', '*' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)))                    
        .AsParallel()
        .Select(word => word.ToLower()) 
        .Where(word => !StopWords.Contains(word))
        .Where(word => !PopulatNetworkWords.Contains(word)) 
        .Where(word => !word.All(char.IsDigit))
        .GroupBy(word => word)                    
        .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the different between the two is whether or not `Distinct()` was called on it, and since `Distinct()` both works on and returns an `IEnumerable<T>` (or works on and returns an `IQueryable<T>`. Then first create the appropriate `IEnumerable<T>`, then decide whether or not to replace it with the result of calling `Distinct()`, and then continue:

```
private void Splitter(string[] file, bool distinct)
{               
  IEnumerable<string> query = file
    .SelectMany(i => File.ReadAllLines(i)
    .SelectMany(line => line.Split(new[] { ' ', ',', '.', '?', '!', '{', '[', '(', '}', ']', ')',
    '<', '>', '-', '=', '/', '"', ';', ':', '+', '_', '*' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))                    
    .AsParallel()
    .Select(word => word.ToLower()) 
    .Where(word => !StopWords.Contains(word))
    .Where(word => !PopulatNetworkWords.Contains(word)) 
    .Where(word => !word.All(char.IsDigit));
  if(distinct)
    query = query.Distinct());
  return query
    .GroupBy(word => word)                    
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
}
```

(Incidentally, you might find that the newer `ReadLines` works better than `ReadAllLines`, especially with large files. `ReadAllLines` reads all the lines into memory immediately, rather than just reading them as you use them, so it wastes a lot of memory and delays processing).

Comment: This will be a little OT, but changing `ReadAllLines` to `ReadLines` is enough? Or it needs something along with it (maybe it return different type of data?)?

Comment: `ReadAllLines` returns `string[]` and `ReadLines` returns `IEnumerable<string>`, but the way you use `ReadAllLines` depends on nothing about `string[]` apart from the fact that it implements `IEnumerable<string>`, so you can simply replace `ReadAllLines` with `ReadLines`. Other replacements might require more work (if it had gone through the array by index), or not even be worth it.

Comment: @BJSafdie or rather, replacing it is.

Comment: @Jon -- Doh. Yes, that is what I meant.  Replacing ReadAllLines is indeed a good optimization.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Why not something like this:

```
    private void Splitter1(string[] file, bool useDistinct = false))
    {
        tempDict = file
            .SelectMany(i => File.ReadAllLines(i)
            .SelectMany(line => line.Split(new[] { ' ', ',', '.', '?', '!', '{', '[', '(', '}', ']', ')',
    '<', '>', '-', '=', '/', '"', ';', ':', '+', '_', '*' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            .AsParallel()
            .Select(word => word.ToLower())
            .Where(word => !StopWords.Contains(word))
            .Where(word => !PopulatNetworkWords.Contains(word))
            .Where(word => !word.All(char.IsDigit))
            .Select(x => useDistinct ? x.Distinct() : x)
            .GroupBy(word => word)
            .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
    }
```

Comment: Here if `useDistinct` is true, `Distinct` is called on each item, rather than on the query, so with "abba", "abc", "abc" instead of getting "abba", "abc" you get "ab", "abc", "abc".

Comment: @Jon Hanna thats correct I edited code, it should be fine now

Answer (score 0):

Since Linq defers execution, you can build the clauses in separate statements.

```
 private void Splitter1(string[] file, bool distinct)
    {               
         var query = file.SelectMany (i => File.ReadAllLines(i)
                .SelectMany(line => line.Split(new[] { ' ', ',', '.', '?', '!', '{', '[', '(', '}', ']', ')',
                '<', '>', '-', '=', '/', '"', ';', ':', '+', '_', '*' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))                    
                .AsParallel()
                .Select(word => word.ToLower()) 
                .Where(word => !StopWords.Contains(word))
                .Where(word => !PopulatNetworkWords.Contains(word)) 
                .Where(word => !word.All(char.IsDigit)));

        if (distinct) 
        {
            query = query.Distinct();
        }
        query.GroupBy(word => word)                    
              .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
    }
```

I did not test this code, so you meay need to adjust it.  However, the basic idea is that deferred execution allows you to vary your query based on logic.

Comment: I like this idea, have to look at it.